# How do I fetch Lab data from Medidata Rave using Rave Web Services?

Tags: web-services

I am able to fetch Medidata Rave study data using Web Services.
Using below URL I am able to fetch data for different form oids:

https://{sponsor url}/RaveWebServices/studies/{study name}/datasets/metadata/regular/{form-oid}

However,in order to fetch Lab data (which is available via UI) I do not have the form-oid to pass.
How do I get the URL to fetch this particular Lab.
I tried exploring Medidata Rave's authentic site learn.mdsol.com for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The form-oid I mentioned above is LAB.csv and the data comes as expected.Providing just LAB doesn't work because LAB data does not come in xml format.